# Parse data from multiple XML files and output to csv file

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, cygwin

I've got a dozen XML files which contain the results of some wcat web performance tests. Within each XML file there is a data node that contains the names of each page requested and the average time it took to load it. I want to extract that information from each XML file and output it to a csv file so I can create a nice pretty graph in excel.

I could do the task in my main working language of C# but in an attempt to improve my scripting skills I'd like to try and do it using unix/cygwin commands or a scripting language such as Ruby.

The format of the XML file is:

```
<report name="wcat" version="6.3.1" level="1" top="100">
 <section name="header" key="90000">
  ... lots of other XML junk...
  <item>
   <data name="reportt" >Request Name I</data>
   ...
   <data name="avgttlb" >628</data>
  </item>
  <item>
   <data name="reportt" >Request Name II</data>
   ...
   <data name="avgttlb" >793</data>
  </item>
  ... lots of other XML junk...
 </section
</report>
```

And the csv output I need is:

```
Request,File 1,File 2,...,File 12
Request Name I,628,123,...,789
Request Name II,793,456,...,987
```

Are there any good cygwin command line utilities that could parse the XML? Or failing that is there a nice way to do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a nice parser called [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), that I really like. It supports both XML and HTML, DOM and SAX, and can build XML if that's your fancy. It's built on libxml2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

xml = <<END_XML
<report name="wcat" version="6.3.1" level="1" top="100">
<section name="header" key="90000">
  <item>
    <data name="reportt" >Request Name I</data>
    <data name="avgttlb" >628</data>
  </item>
  <item>
    <data name="reportt" >Request Name II</data>
    <data name="avgttlb" >793</data>
  </item>
  </section
</report>
END_XML

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
content = doc.search('item').map { |i| 
  i.search('data').map { |d| d.text }
}

content.each do |c|
  puts c.join(',')
end

# >> Request Name I,628
# >> Request Name II,793
```

Notice that Nokogiri allows use of CSS accessors, which I'm using here, in addition to the standard XPath accessors. The actual parsing took the middle four lines.

Ruby's got a built-in CSV generator/parser, but for this quick 'n dirty example I didn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing could be done in XSLT, which supports text output method, multiple input files (using the `document()` function), and of course templates.

I know some people find XSLT gross, but I use it all the time for this kind of thing and rather like it.  Plus it's pretty much platform-independent.

Answer (score 1):

in python...

```
import elementTree.ElementTree
import csv

result = []
tree = elementTree.ElemenTree.parse('test.xml')
section = tree.getroot().find('section')
items = section.findall('item')
for item in items:
    records = item.findall('data')
    row = [rec.text for rec in records]
    result.append(row)

csv.writer(file('output.csv', 'w'))
csv.writerows(result)
```

Comment: Excuse my python newbness but how d I get the elementTree module? I'm on Windows 7 and do have the main Python distribution installed.